# How to handle a MySQL table which is keep increasing quickly?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, cluster-computing, data-management

I have a table named `transactions`, something like this:

```
id | user_id | business_id | amount | tracking_code | status | created_at | updated_at
```

As you can see, this is a table which keeps all transactions. Currently it has over 50M rows and every day about 4k new rows get added to it. I'm worried about one or two next years that the business scaled up and I will end up with a really huge table.

Currently we have two indexes on this table for a better search performance. Also the engine is `innodb`.

Any idea how it should be handled generally?

In the side of hardware resources, I'm completely ok to increase the server hardware when needed. But I guess, the issue will be managing the data in the future and not the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Disk space is cheap.  You have, what, 3.2 GB in data and some factor on top of that in indexes.  If the applications doesn't need all the data to be online, then you have the option of archive old data (dump then delete from table).  You can look into [compression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-compression.html) as an option.  Possibly in combination with some of the [alternative storage engines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about application performance with 1 billion rows on a machine that can keep the indexes in memory.

However, I would suggest making the id columns as BigInt if you know that the table is growing at a fast pace as a 32-bit integer will be limited to 2^31-1= 2,147,483,647 rows

The performance of your table and search engine depends on:

1. How many join those queries do on this particular table?
2. How well your indexes are set up? Apparently good
3. How much RAM is in the machine hosting the DB?
4. Speed and number of processors related to it?
5. Size of the row/amount of data returned in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about how many CPUs and their speed.  That is rarely the limiting factor in MySQL.

Do you need either `created_at` or `updated_at`?

Don't bother with compression; it is unlikely to be worth it.

Do use smaller datatypes where practical (and conservative).

Stick with InnoDB.  There are many reasons; I won't repeat them here.

Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the critical queries.  We may have more tips.